# CSS / HTML5: transparent layer with after pseudo-element over fullscreen video tag?

Tags: css, html, video

I'm trying to do this:

```
<video id="test" loop autoplay>
    <source src="assets/videos/h264.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="assets/videos/h264.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="assets/videos/h264.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

#test:after {
    content: "";
    background: #000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Why is this not working? Looks like this for me … http://jsfiddle.net/13knrneg/

If I replace the video tag with a div it works 100%. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The `video` tag doesn't support pseudo classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700951/before-after-pseudo-class-not-working-on-video-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position: relative` for the **video** block and `position: absolute` for top pseudo-layer.

Try this:

```
#test {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#test:after {
    content: " ";
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can [see the updated result here](http://jsfiddle.net/13knrneg/1/).

Comment: This does not work. It seems the `<video>` tag does not support pseudo-elements.