# ::before/::after pseudo class not working on video element

Tags: html, css, video

I would like my video element to show a title over the video while it's playing, the problem is: it doesn't work. If I switch the <video> tag to a <div> it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

My HTML markup is this:

```
<div class="player">
    <video src="video.mp4" poster="video-poster.jpg" title="Video Name"></video>
</div>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
.player {
    position: relative;
    width: 852px;
    height: 356px;
}
.player video {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
}
.player video::after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can't add a :pseudo-element to a `video` tag.

Comment: Thanks, explains alot. Is there a reason for this? Any documentation?

Comment: You could read more about pseudo-elements here ----> http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: To solve your problem you could always add a pseudo-element to the container `div`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as now I have to use a JavaScript solution to transfer the video's "title" attribute to it's parent.

Comment: `video` tags have "closed" shadow roots, so you can't modify them with pseudo elements — https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#closed

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using `:before` or `:after` on a `<video>` tag won't work. You will also find this the case (sadly) with HTML input controls (e.g. textboxes).

This is because of the way `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements work. They are box model objects that work e.g. like a `div` but are placed *inside* their parent element. Elements like input text boxes and videos cannot contain child elements as far as content is concerned (video has src child tags but that is different).

E.g. if you had HTML:

```
<div class="awesome-highlight">
...
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.awesome-highlight::after {
    content: 'Hello World';
}
```

The rendered *effect* will be:

```
<div class="awesome-highlight"> 
... 
Hello World
</div>
```

**More info:**

W3: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

Old Stackoverflow answer: [Which elements support the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements)

Comment: If anyone else is wondering what to do, you can add a `div` immediately after your video tag that is also `position:absolute` and style accordingly (e.g. CSS gradient, etc) like this: https://codepen.io/oscar-jite/pen/OJZVzOo